# Scaling values in dataframe column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, scaling

I have a dataframe and I want to scale the values in each column to range from (0,1) and do not want to manually compute myself for each column. I saw sklearn's MinMaxScaler but I am not sure how to call this? To reiterate, I would want to call this on each column in the dataframe and ideally make the changes in place: `MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1), copy=False)`. I am open to other simple approaches as well.

Comment: MinMaxScaler as defined in documentation works on numpy arrays. You may pass the dataframe, but it will result a numpy array. It has a parameter named `copy` which can be set to `False` to perform inplace transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this buddy

```
df['normal_var'] = (df.var - df.var.min()) / (df.var.max() -df.var.min())
```